# Why does the directive see $ index but not $ parent AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I did untill now

https://plnkr.co/edit/14LM5VhORXMa1lD7jm7U?p=preview

and I need have in directiv $parent.$index too, it can be sent or not? someone can me explain this?

```
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in lists"> 
          {{item.name}}
             <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="card in item.cards">
                 {{card.name}}

                  <div modal-window-card></div>  
               </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-repeat creates a new scope so the second ng-repeat will be in the first ng-repeats scope. The way to reach the first ng-repeats scopes $index is by using

```
$parent.$index
```

But as you use a directive which also creates a new scope using $parent will only reach the second ng-repeats scope. To reach the first ng-repeats scope use

```
App.directive('modalWindowCard', function(){
  return {
        scope: {

        },
        template:  '{{$parent.$parent.$index}}/{{$parent.$index}}' 

  }
})
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Yo3YtROYFNDYBcnNLSVi?p=preview)

Comment: ok but why $ index does not have to add but $ parent already yes

Comment: Hey, can u tell me one more thing, if I want in directiv write {{card.name}} is undefined then i must send by parameter i do that and still nothing, can you help me? https://plnkr.co/edit/zR1cGzlsPMvn6kC20nS9?p=preview

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska doesn't my answer solve this question? u should accept the answer then we can look at new requirement

Comment: Hey thanks !, last question with is differences between modal-window-card card="card" and modal-window-card = "card"  because in second way i had only card.name i think and in ur way i have everything